# Small Search box customization gets overwritten on Search Result page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

I have built a custom master page that we're using throughout the site which features a customized SmallSearchBox control which  i have implemented using best practice:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Control 
        Id="SmallSearchInputBox" 
        Sequence="10"
        ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx" ControlAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Property Name="GoImageUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearch15.png</Property>
      <Property Name="GoImageUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/gosearchrtl15.png</Property>
      <Property Name="GoImageActiveUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearchhover15.png</Property>
      <Property Name="GoImageActiveUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/gosearchrtlhover15.png</Property>
      <Property Name="DropDownMode">ShowDD</Property>
    <Property Name="SearchResultPageURL">/Search/pages/results.aspx</Property>
    <Property Name="ScopeDisplayGroupName"></Property>
    <Property Name="FrameType">None</Property>
   </Control>    
</Elements>
```

I used the sequence number 10 and it works ok.  However, we created search sub-site and and the page results.aspx.  The site uses the same master page.  However, on that page the search box theme looks different which throws all of my customizations off.
Has anyone dealt with this issue?  I would like to avoid building a custom master page and specific inherited control SmallSearchBoxEx. I feel like i am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the Search Results page doesn't use the SmallSearchInputBox placeholder (in fact the page layout just overrides this placeholder), but rather uses the Search WebPart which AFAIK cannot be overriden via a DelegateControl feature.

So your options are:

1. Change the WebPart properties to change the search image
2. Use CSS to change the search image

Comment: I am using a custom page with my own page layout and my own master page.  The mast page contains the delegate control placeholder which does get customized by SearchBoxEx definition but it seems that my own definition does not get applied entirely.

Comment: Did you also use a customized "results.aspx" page? That's the page I'm talking about.

Comment: i created a brand new page in the Search site, and then applied a custom page layout.